# How should the keychain option be used for altool?

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect, application-loader

I'm trying to use the `@keychain` option with the `-p` switch in altool in order to load my iTunes Connect password from the keychain:

```
altool --validate-app -f "${IPA}" -u "redacted" -p "@keychain:?????"
```

I'm trying to figure out what I need to enter after `@keychain:`. Everything I try (path of the keychain file, name of the keychain entry, username in the keychain entry) produces the following error:

> *** Error: The specified item could not be found in the keychain.

`altool` supplies the following info about the `-p` param:

```
-p, --password  Password. Required if username specified.  Password is read from stdin if one is not supplied.
                May use @keychain: or @env: prefixes followed by the keychain or environment variable lookup name.
                e.g. -p @env:SECRET which would use the value in the SECRET environment variable.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct usage is to enter the name of the keychain item (not the name of the keychain itself, and not the "Account" field for the keychain item).

My problem was actually related to access control. I had to edit the keychain item in Keychain Access and tweak the Access Control settings to allow `altool` to see the keychain item.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating a bit?  I've tried `altool --validate-app -f "${IPA}" -u "redacted" -p "@keychain:iPhone Distribution: Example Company, LLC"` but it's never able to find the identity.  I've tried unlocking the keychain and giving full access control with no luck.
`

Comment: Sorry that I wasn't clear about that. I honestly don't remember, and am no longer working on that codebase so I can't check… feel free to edit this question and/or answer if you figure it out.

Comment: After working fine for over a year, it stopped working. The problem was the Access Control as well. For some reason, the Keychain only had the iCloud version of the credentials, where you cannot modify permissions.
I ended up making a new entry with the same password, where I could change the Access Control to allow `altool`.

Answer (score 16):

Prerequisites:

- You need an Apple developer account, obviously. That's `AC_USERNAME`.
- You need a password for that account. If you can have two-factor authentication enabled, you need to create an *app-specific password* (beyond the scope of this answer). The password is `AC_PASSWORD`.
- The keychain item is going to need a name that is references via `altool`'s `@keychain` parameter. We call this `ITEM_NAME`.

**In the instructions below, replace `AC_USERNAME`, `AC_PASSWORD` and `ITEM_NAME` with the values you need. Do not type these names verbatim.**

Now:

1. Create a generic password in your keychain.

   - You can do so via `Keychain Access.app` *File > New Password Item …* . In the *Keychain Item Name*, enter the name you want for `ITEM_NAME`, the *Account Name* is your `AC_USERNAME` and the `AC_PASSWORD` goes into the *Password* field.
   - Or you can do it via the command line: `security add-generic-password -a "AC_USERNAME" -w "AC_PASSWORD" -s "ITEM_NAME"`
2. In the arguments to `altool`, you now pass `-u AC_USERNAME -p "@keychain:ITEM_NAME"` to make it fetch the password from the keychain.
3. The first time you run `altool`, you get a security confirmation dialog asking you whether to allow `altool` to read the password. Enter your keychain password and click on `Always allow`.

To prevent the security confirmation dialog from appearing, either click on `Always allow` or modify the appropriate keychain entry. This works like this:

- Locate the path to `altool` by opening a shell and typing `xcrun -find altool`.
- Either use this path as argument `-T <path>` when creating the password using the `security add-generic-password` command or:

  - Open `Keychain Access.app`.
  - Select the password entry, select the menu `File > Get Info` (or press Cmd+I or click the `ⓘ` icon).
  - In this dialog, select the `Access Control` tab and press the `+` button. A file selection dialog opens.
  - Open Finder and select the menu `Go > Go to Folder…` and paste the path to `altool` (the directory part, without `altool` itself, e.g. `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/`).
  - Drag `altool` to the open panel of `Keychain Access` and press the `Add` button.

Comment: is possible to avoid the dialog asking for keychain password? (Step 3) I want to automatise the process

Comment: @RuLoViC: See my edit for details on how it should work.

Comment: I would need to achieve that using command line, because it is part of automatic build. Is that possible ?

Comment: Which part do you mean with "achieve that"? Using `altool` without the security dialog? That's what my edit was about.

Comment: But according to your edit you still need to do some things using Graphical Interface. I cannot do that since it will be part of automatised build

Comment: a) You missed the part about passing `-T <path>` to `security`.  b) If you actually generate a keychain entry _during your automated build_ then you must have the password in plaintext already and should skip the keychain altogether. Just pass the password to `altool` using `-p <myrawpassword>` instead of `-p @keychain:<keychainitemname>`.

Comment: Finally I used your solution. Now I have different problem: 2019-06-19 21:41:59.620 altool[35802:70182] *** Error: To use this application, you must first sign in to iTunes Connect and sign the relevant contracts. (1048) Have ever had this problem ?

Comment: @RuLoViC: You probably need to sign in to https://developer.apple.com with that account and confirm all license agreements there.

Answer (score 13):

The way that worked for me was logging in with the **Application Loader** itself (check the "Keep me logged in" option) and use the keychain entry of the **Application Loader**.

So my command looks like this:

```
altool --validate-app -f APPLICATION.ipa -u my@apple.id -p @keychain:"Application Loader: my@apple.id"
```

Comment: I opened Xcode's ApplicationLoader, Windows > Sign Out.  All was good after I signed in again and checked "[x] Keep Me Signed In". My command line Jenkins build job that uses altool now works again.  Thank you!

Comment: This probably shouldn't be the accepted answer but it is nonetheless very useful!