# Which password I should use for altool command line?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-bots, xcode-server-bots

Trying to execute altool command, but it fails, that password is incorrect:

```
xcrun altool --list-apps -u user@domain.com -p PASSWORD
```

- I did try to use my user name password.
- I did try to use @keychain functionality failing, that it is failing because keychain item not found. I did fallow this [instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40344627/1151916). It is failing with this message: ***Error: Failed to read legacy keychain item***

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Login to https://appleid.apple.com/
2. Generate APP-SPECIFIC PASSWORD
   [image]
3. Save generated password as later it will not be able to view and
   edit
4. Use generated password in the altool.

###### Example:

```
xcrun altool --validate-app -f best/my/app.ipa -u username@mail.com -p "APP-SPECIFIC-PASSWORD"
```

Notes: After changing users password all app specific passwords will be revoked.

Answer (score 5):

The **failed to read legacy keychain item** is simply because you put the password in your keychain a long time ago and OS X has had several updates in the mean time.  Simply run the store command again:

> xcrun altool --store-password-in-keychain-item "AL_TOOL" -u
> "" -p ""

You can remove the old item if it is still there.  Now your script can read the password with -p "@keychain:AL_TOOL".

Answer (score 1):

I only get this error if I place the password in an iCloud keychain. If I open Keychain Access and add a password item with specifically selecting "**login**" keychain, altool is able to read from it without an error.